# Javascript DATE and C# date - what is the best solution?

Tags: c#, javascript, json, datetime

I am getting a date from server side C# using the following code:

```
DateTime d1 = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
DateTime d2 = (DateTime)c.ccdTimestamp2;
long x = new TimeSpan(d2.Ticks - d1.Ticks).TotalMilliseconds;
```

When I get my code on the javascript side:

```
function (timestamp) {
    alert("testing :" + new Date(timestamp))
}
```

This gives me a fully formatted date but it does not bring the time of my timezone since if it is 17.15 here, it provides me with 19.15 GMT +2 !

At first  I simply tried to pass my c# timestamp, without any of the code above and found this question: [How do I format a Microsoft JSON date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-to-format-a-json-date) But I have no idea what JSON is and I couldn't derive what I can do! Is it easier to use JSON? If so can anyone guide me? Thank you very much

---

Edit: The Solution
 - I did not use universal time on the server side. I left server side code as it is. All I did is this:

```
new Date(timestamp).toUTCString()
```

Comment: Are the server and the client located in different timezones?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you should do is:

- Always use UTC times on the server
- Send UTC times to the browser as unit time stamps as you do now
- Convert the time stamp to local time in the browser

The timestamp used represents: `2012-04-11T15:46:29+00:00`:

```
var d = new Date ( 1334159189000 );
// gives you back 2012-04-11T15:46:29+00:00 in a slightly different format, but the timezone info matches UTC/GMT+0
d.toUTCString();
// gives you back your local time
d.toLocaleString();
```

Just created a jsfiddle to show that it does what it is supposed to:
http://jsfiddle.net/t8hNs/1/

​

Comment: When i try with my C# ticks it's not working. The time ticks is : 635834482125955879

Answer (score 4):

use

```
var currentDate = new Date();
//get off set from your browser
var offset = Date.getTimezoneOffset();
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)

```
string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: I can't even reference System.Web.Script... :/

Comment: @test And I can't see a way to help ones `who can't even reference System.Web.Script` :/

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot find it in the references under 'system' tab. Or should I be searching some where else?

Comment: @test Click on the link in my answer. It will show you the namespace and the assembly you need